# How to Set Back Ground Color of text occupied area alone in QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to set a background colour of **text occupied area Only**, in QLabel ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class myList(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.myui()

    def myui(self):

        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.label_head = QLabel("Company Name")
        self.textbox.setFixedSize(400,30)
        self.label_head.setFont(QFont("caliber",12,QFont.Bold))
        self.label_head.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_head.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;")
        self.label_head.adjustSize()
        self.label_head.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label_head)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = myList()
    mywin.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this code, I need a background color to text area only ( "Company name").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
self.label_head = QLabel("<span style='color: #fff; background-color: #00f'>Company Name</span>")
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class myList(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame Example")
        self.myui()

    def myui(self):

        self.textbox = QLineEdit()

        self.label_head = QLabel("<span style='color: #fff; background-color: #00f'>Company Name</span>") # <---

        self.textbox.setFixedSize(400,30)
        self.label_head.setFont(QFont("caliber",12,QFont.Bold))
        self.label_head.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_head.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;border-radius:5px;padding:2px;")
        self.label_head.adjustSize()
        self.label_head.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label_head)
        vbox.addWidget(self.textbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

def main():
    myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = myList()
    mywin.show()
    sys.exit(myapp.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: hai, @s.Nick , but its not work at the time of chage text, self.label_head.setText("Addresss")

Comment: @Bala  try it `self.label_head.setText("<span style='color: #fff; background-color: #00f'>Addresss</span>") `

Comment: Works fine @s.Nick

Comment: @S.Nick, Is there any other way to get it ?